# Where to get lightweight belts for bjj competitions from?

Tags: brazilian-jiu-jitsu, belt

Is there any company that specialized on this? My main belt is rather heavy, would be great to get a lighter one to wear during competitions, so that I'll have to cut a little less weight :D
Any website that compares belt manufacturers? I think it's quite a niche product, although everyone needs a belt to keep their gi together :D

How much does a lightweight belt weigh, to be able to identify one?

Comment: Found this on reddit: https://www.reddit.com/r/bjj/comments/40aney/good_lightweight_belt/

Comment: Don't you weigh in without a gi?

Comment: Nope, also the weigh-ins are usually on the same day as the matches...

Comment: Yeah, just put on silk pajamas for the weigh-in and do a quick-change later. Either that or wait for carbon nanotube fabric to become a thing. :)

Comment: The uniform that you weigh in with has to be conform to the rules. Finding a lightweight gi is also a thing. But this question is specifically for the belts.

Comment: Aren't weight ins made in underware? Anyway does 200g make such a difference?

Comment: 200g that is 2 chocolate bars. :) it's not a big difference but a measurable one

Comment: @JorgeCanelhas He's probably doing IBJJF tournaments, a horrific organization known for their overbearing membership policies, belt registrations, absurdly restrictive rule sets, and of course, silly weigh in practices.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the Reddit link provided in the comments, I have found these two companies that have lighter weight belts. You can see from the image of all of these belts that they are not as thick as your normal BJJ belt. They appear to be made more similarly to a Taekwondo belt. These are the best ones I found:

[**ASAMI Jiu Jitsu Belts:**](http://isami-kimonos.com/index.php?genre_id=27&htpl_id=8)

[**Howard Combat BJJ ProGear Belt**](https://www.jiujitsuprogear.com/category-s/56.htm) (Not the Venom Belt)

[**OTM Vulkan Gui Belt**](https://onthemat.myshopify.com/collections/bjj-belts/products/vulkan-gi-belt)

*This Killer Bee appears the lightest from the material it's made of*:

[**Killer Bee BJJ Weave Belt:**](http://www.killerbeegi.com/killerbeegi-bjj-weave-belts/)